# muenchian sum based on multiple grouping and adding termination

Tags: xml, xslt, grouping, muenchian-grouping

I want to obtain a better xml file using some xslt and xml
below.Please provide XSLT 1.0 support .Thanks a lot.

```
<!-- entry xml -->
    <Pallets>
    <Pallet>
    <PalletNumber>2</PalletNumber>
    <Product>1</Product>
    <Quantity>2</Quantity>
    </Pallet>
    <Pallet>
    <PalletNumber>2</PalletNumber>
    <Product>1</Product>
    <Quantity>4</Quantity>
    </Pallet>
    <Pallet>
    <PalletNumber>2</PalletNumber>
    <Product>2</Product>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
    </Pallet>
    <Pallet>
    <PalletNumber>3</PalletNumber>
    <Product>1</Product>
    <Quantity>2</Quantity>
    </Pallet>
    <Pallet>
    <PalletNumber>4</PalletNumber>
    <Product>2</Product>
    <Quantity>2</Quantity>
    </Pallet></Pallets>
```

I need to sum up quantity per pallet number and product(see first node
below) .Also sequence number is needed in the right part of
palletnumber value based on first appearance in the xml.Results should
look like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- upgraded xml --> 
    <Pallets><Pallet>
    <PalletNumber>2_1</PalletNumber>
    <Product>1</Product>
    <Quantity>6</Quantity>
    </Pallet>
    <Pallet>
    <PalletNumber>2_2</PalletNumber>
    <Product>2</Product>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
    </Pallet>
    <Pallet>
    <PalletNumber>3_1</PalletNumber>
    <Product>1</Product>
    <Quantity>2</Quantity>
    </Pallet>
    <Pallet>
    <PalletNumber>4_1</PalletNumber>
    <Product>2</Product>
    <Quantity>2</Quantity>
    </Pallet></Pallets>
```

Comment: +1 for a good first question although an example of what you've already tried would've been nice.

Answer (score 3):

Not 100% sure the logic for the new `PalletNumber` is correct (it's 3:00 AM here), but the following XSLT 1.0 returns the desired output with the given input...

**XML Input**

```
<Pallets>
    <Pallet>
        <PalletNumber>2</PalletNumber>
        <Product>1</Product>
        <Quantity>2</Quantity>
    </Pallet>
    <Pallet>
        <PalletNumber>2</PalletNumber>
        <Product>1</Product>
        <Quantity>4</Quantity>
    </Pallet>
    <Pallet>
        <PalletNumber>2</PalletNumber>
        <Product>2</Product>
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
    </Pallet>
    <Pallet>
        <PalletNumber>3</PalletNumber>
        <Product>1</Product>
        <Quantity>2</Quantity>
    </Pallet>
    <Pallet>
        <PalletNumber>4</PalletNumber>
        <Product>2</Product>
        <Quantity>2</Quantity>
    </Pallet>
</Pallets>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:key name="kPalletProduct" match="Pallet" use="concat(PalletNumber,'-',Product)"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Pallets">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select="Pallet[generate-id()=generate-id(key('kPalletProduct',concat(PalletNumber,'-',Product))[1])]">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <PalletNumber>
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat(PalletNumber,'_',count(preceding::Pallet[PalletNumber=current()/PalletNumber and not(Product=current()/Product)][1])+1)"/>
                    </PalletNumber>
                    <Product>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Product"/>
                    </Product>
                    <Quantity>
                        <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('kPalletProduct',concat(PalletNumber,'-',Product))/Quantity)"/>
                    </Quantity>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<Pallets>
   <Pallet>
      <PalletNumber>2_1</PalletNumber>
      <Product>1</Product>
      <Quantity>6</Quantity>
   </Pallet>
   <Pallet>
      <PalletNumber>2_2</PalletNumber>
      <Product>2</Product>
      <Quantity>1</Quantity>
   </Pallet>
   <Pallet>
      <PalletNumber>3_1</PalletNumber>
      <Product>1</Product>
      <Quantity>2</Quantity>
   </Pallet>
   <Pallet>
      <PalletNumber>4_1</PalletNumber>
      <Product>2</Product>
      <Quantity>2</Quantity>
   </Pallet>
</Pallets>
```